# Can't connect Postgres through DataGrip On Mac M1 Pro

Tags: postgresql, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I created a pg container using `docker run --name pg -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456 -p 5432:5432 -d postgres`

[image]

and I could connect it by psql, see above:

[image]

But I can't connect it by DataGrip, Why?
the error in the picture is above:

[image]

```
DBMS: PostgreSQL (ver. 12.16)
Case sensitivity: plain=mixed, delimited=exact
The connection attempt failed.
```

I tried on my another laptop, it's mac pro 2018 and chip is Intel, But to my great surprise, it was  success. same command with different result.

Comment: Does it help if you use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` in the connection settings in DataGrip?

Comment: 1) I am not seeing the password included in the URL. Is it being set in an `env` variable outside the the container? 2) Look at the Postgres log to see if it offers more information then the rather lame error message from DataGrip.

Comment: @Koyasha no help, I tried at the beginning

Comment: password is included but it is hidden in the input box

Comment: anyone has a macbook m1 chip can have a try

Comment: Look at the screenshot in particular the `URL:` part, where it says *Overrides settings above*. In the URL there is no user( I just noticed) or password for user. I don't use DataGrip so I'm guessing here, but I would remove the URL setting and see if that helps.

Comment: @LixLi were you able to solve this ? facing similar issue

Answer (score 0):

To [run correctly](https://dev.to/docker/choosing-the-right-docker-image-for-your-apple-m1-pro-440l) PostgreSQL on your Apple M1 Pro [choose arm64v8 image](https://hub.docker.com/r/arm64v8/postgres/).
In your case it would be like:

```
docker run --name pg -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456 -p 5432:5432 -d arm64v8/postgres
```

Answer (score -1):

Your main environment listens 0.0.0.0:5432 and redirects to the container' s 5432 ports. So, you need provide hostname as 0.0.0.0 and port 5432.